# Can a recursive function write to a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, recursion

I'm going to have two class functions.  The first class function opens the file.  Then it calls a second function that writes to the file and recursively calls itself.  When the second function finishes, the original function closes the file.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes. What's your specific problem?

Comment: I was just thinking that the second function would not be able to know the file name.

Comment: @Phenom It doesn't need the file name - it needs the file handle/descriptor/whatever that can be passed to it as a a parameter.

Comment: @Phenom:  Don't close the file in the recursive function.

Comment: @Thomas: you are a master of Murphy's Law.

Comment: @Phenom: You should put those kinds of concerns into your question so we have a better idea of what you're asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, as long as you pass the file handle/object to the recursive function:

```
void recursion(int data, int maxdepth, ostream &os)
{
    // must eventually break out
    if (maxdepth == 0)
        return;

    // write data
    os << data << std::endl;

    // and call one deeper
    recursion(data + 1, maxdepth - 1, os);
}

void start(const char *filename)
{
    std::ofstream os(filename);

    recursion(0, 100, os);
}
```

Comment: I prefer to do the level backwards. That way, the caller sees `recursion(100, os)` and knows that it will recurse 100 levels deep. That's more informative than seeing `recursion(0, os)` and having to know that it will recurse 100 - 0 = 100 levels deep. But that's just me.

Comment: @ChrisLutz - I like that idea as that lets the caller determine how far to recurse.  I actually made the data separate from the maxdepth to show how they can be independent (because while this toy example the data is a counter, in a real example, it could be something else).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's perfectly possible.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as long as your recursive function has a base case, it will terminate.

```
func2(int p) {
  if (p == 0) return;
  //write
  func2(--p);
}

func() {
  //open file
  func2(10);
  //close file
}
```

Comment: You are using post decrement in `func2(p--)` so you will call the next func2 with the same value this func2 was called with so your recursion will never terminate.  You need to either do `func2(--p)` or `func2(p - 1)`.

Comment: I _knew_ there was a reason I preferred `recursive(i - 1)` to `recursive(i--)` or `recursive(--i)`. That was it. @R Samuel is right, the code you give will iterate forever (or perhaps until a stack overflow happens if the compiler doesn't optimize this). I prefer `func2(p - 1)` because a) there's no reason to use `--`, since we never need the value of `p` again, and b) we have no risk of using `p--` and expecting it to work, even though `p--` returns the original value of `p`, causing this to recurse forever.

Answer (score 3):

Yes because the write calls are sequencial even if that sequence is defined recursivly. The file object sees nothing but a linear serise of write calls, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Nothing in C++ or the file system will prevent you from doing this.